# Virtual Machine for software renting service

Tags: windows, virtualization, unix, virtual-machines

I am currently trying to figure out which solution would be best for software renting service (with proper licensing and stuff). I know its kinda stupid and so on, but I just have to develop it.

Long story short - user can connect to a virtual machine (with windows guest os) using vnc and use some specific software for some specific time (eg., 1 hour).

I have already considered VirtualBox, Xen and some other, but maybe somebody has a better idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you seerious? I mean, from ALL solutions I ahve seen (TS, Citrix) you choose the worst one - VNC sucks for anything when you can use a better tech. Ever heard of Remote desktop? For Hypervisor - use hyper-V. It is free because you will likely need to SPLA (! - no purchase legal) a DataCenter edition anyway (for the virtualization rights), which comes with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use terminal services? or citrix?

Comment: I dont know if terminal services are compatible with vnc. I need vnc because we have flash vnc viewer. The rental software has to be available directly in web browser. Anyway thanks for those options, I will do a deeper research.

Comment: They ar not, but they allow publication of SOFTWARE (not screens) and they are a LOT faster. VNS sucks, performance wise, compared to Terminal Server / Citrix. I klnow some software on the go, and it all uses publshed software (you only see the windows of your application, not the desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I have used keyserver extensively in public companies in the US and UK. It does a pretty good job. I haven't looked at their API or extensions, though.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare Server supports using VNC as a remote console.  Some versions of it are free, you could check those out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a solution from [2X](http://www.2x.com) which is much more affordable compare to Citrix. When you plan to have the service delivered to your client desktop then you may consider to publish only a fraction of your application using Application Server schema which is provided as one of the software solution on 2x

Answer (score 0):

2X Software just released [2X ApplicationServer XG](http://www.2x.com/applicationserver/) with a SaaS licencing model. Might be what you are looking for. Here is [some info](http://www.2x.com/blog/2011/12/products-releases/2x-applicationserver/2x-software-releases-cost-efficient-application-and-desktop-cloud-solution-for-saas-providers/).